# Reporting for Java base Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jasper-reports, reporting

Is there any guide for doing reports for Google App Engine (Java base)? Is Jasper Report compliant to GAE?

Comment: None really gives an exact answer. Many said Jasper Report is not compatible, but then the posts were 2009/2010. And now 2012, I wonder how far did Jasper Report go for?

Comment: And also there're only very little comment on using Google Conversion API. Oh by the way, Google Conversion API just deprecated. It migrated into Google Drive. Oh well, to use it, it stated "VERY EXPERIMENTAL". By that means, use by your own risk =.='

Comment: PDF Jet is not freebie, too bad.

Comment: Someone claimed iText > v5.2.0 has now compatible with GAE. I will giv e it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using

http://code.google.com/p/xdocreport/

and very satisfied with that.

They recently made a small modification on my request to make things GAE compliant. see [here](http://code.google.com/p/xdocreport/issues/detail?id=132&can=1&q=appengine).

Comment: Really thanks! This is something better I see :) By the way, does it support PDF output? Not really go in details.

Comment: I wonder how did those GAE developers actually survive without an actual GAE Reporting APIs?

Comment: they have a converter to PDF based on iText, but I read the transformations can be cumbersome. I use it for odt->odt or docx->docx; creating templates was never easier !

Comment: Hell, I wonder how did GAE actually support for reporting engine all this time???

Comment: GREAT! iText has actually fixed couples java.awt issue by replacing it to low level api :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try  workaround below :

1) Store your report using Google Docs ( using Google Docs API ).

2) convert the doc to PDF using Google Docs API. Refer to this [example](http://blog.programmableweb.com/2009/02/20/google-api-now-lets-you-get-documents-in-many-formats/).

Comment: Google Docs deprecated too. I don't dare to use Google Services now, they deprecate in anytime =.='

Comment: I am not sure why they deprecate some very useful API, but I believe it related to public widely abuse since it is free. Now things are stuck.

Comment: I just tried out iText, everything is cool except GAE doesn't support java.awt.Color. I am finding other way to crack this matter.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Cloud Platforms allows you to run an independant Jaspersoft Server in the same project as the AppEngine. Because of that, there is really no reason to run it inside of the AppEngine itself. Just have your servlet utilize Jaspersoft's version 2 of the RESTful web services and return the Jasper Report in any of the supported formats you desire.

Comment: We tried this but there are authentication problems with the JasperReports® Server from Google App Engine (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45163680/appengine-urlfetchservice-removing-custom-response-header-attribute/45164536#45164536)

Comment: How so? I am still use this with no issues.

Comment: We have problems with the login on JasperReports® Server from Google App Engine. The JasperReports server returns a 200 OK status for the login POST request but the "Set-Cookie" attribute never appears in the response header.  Stand-alone tests with Apache HTTP client work fine, but  it seems URLFetchService is removing this "Set-Cookie" attribute. See our post; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45163680/appengine-urlfetchservice-removing-custom-response-header-attribute/45164536#45164536 How did you get this up and running?